# expand second column of glossaries/abbreviation list

Tags: glossaries

I'm currently using the `glossaries` package to describe a few abbreviations/acronyms, I have defined all my acronyms with `\gls{}`...

My glossary list however makes an enter at the middle of the page, I don't know why. Does anyone know how I can expand the second column to describe all the text on one line?

I can't paste the whole preamble, because it contains confidential information and is 3 pages long.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which entry on which middle? Vertically in middle? Horizontally in the middle? Try `style=long` (I suspect you have `style=long3`)

Comment: I'm currently using `code` \usepackage[toc, nogroupskip, nonumberlist, nopostdot, style = super]{glossaries}. My current issue is that some of the lines are divided over two rows, but I want the information to be on the same line. e.g. MPS : separated after massively..

Comment: Try `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}`, i.e. increasing the width of the description column. But this will not work if the description content is just too wide for this width -- it will wrap then. In this you have to use a smaller font, for example

Comment: it looks like this sample was set on a two-column page.  that is usually a function of the document class.  you need to determine whether there is an available one-column option, and make it apply to this page.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer . Problem effectively solved. You're a life saver!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

Apparently the O.P. has too wide descriptions. Using

```
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
```

will increase the width of the description column used in the `long` and other glossaries styles.

However, if the text is still wider, it will be wrapped around.